# Weak derivative of a piecewise defined function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am currently looking at [these](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf) online notes on PDEs, page 59.

How does it follow that if $f^R = \phi(x/R) f(x)$

$
  \phi(x) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    1 & \text{if $|x|\leq 1,$}\\
    0 & \text{if $|x|\geq 2.$}\\
  \end{array}\right.
$

then

$\partial^\alpha f^R=\phi^R\partial^\alpha f+\frac{1}{R}h^R$

How have we worked out the derivative here? Is it a weak derivative? The function is not even defined in between $|x| \in (1,2)$. We the Leibnitz rule has been employed, but how is $h^R$ known to be bounded?

As far as I can see we have $\partial^\alpha f^R = \phi^R \partial^\alpha f+ \frac{1}{R}(\partial^\alpha \phi )(x/R) $

Comment: Could it be that $\phi$ is supposed to be a (smooth?) cut-off function? Or it could be that it's a typo and $\phi(x) = 0$ for $\lvert x\rvert > 1$. Also, what is $h$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes it is supposed to be a cutoff function. If so is it not a typo?

Comment: For cut-off functions, it's not unusual to only say where (at least) they are $1$ and where (at least) they are $0$, in between, the function in some manner decreases from $1$ to $0$, it's usually not important in exactly which manner, and hence that is left unspecified.

Comment: I see that makes more sense now. Of course the derivative will be bounded in that unspecified region and it is zero everywhere else.

Comment: Is this function just the convolution with the standard mollifier with the unit ball?

Comment: It could be the convolution of the characteristic function of a ball with radius $1 < r < 2$ with "the" standard mollifier. One needs a radius strictly larger than $1$, for otherwise the convolution couldn't have value $1$ up to the unit sphere. But as it is left unspecified, one could also make a different construction. However, the details usually don't matter.

Comment: This has been helpful thank you - if you would like to sum this up as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: To add support to Daniel's comments, the paper introduces $\phi$ by the phrase "let $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ be a cut-off function such that $$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |x| \le 1\\0 & |x| \ge 2\end{cases}$$. I.e., the condition on $\phi$ was not a definition, but just a requirement that any candidate function must meet. Other than also being a cut-off function and smooth, $\phi$ is arbitrary.